# Convert Julian date to calendar date

Tags: r, performance, data.table

First, a reproducible example. I am using data.table because I am dealing with around 20 million rows -

```
> require(data.table)

> x <- structure(list(DoM = c(2011241L, 2015359L, 2016352L, 2015360L, 
2015287L, 2014038L, 2017066L, 2012227L, 2015041L, 2015295L), 
Year = c(2011L, 2015L, 2016L, 2015L, 2015L, 2014L, 2017L, 
2012L, 2015L, 2015L), Month = c(8L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 10L, 2L, 
3L, 8L, 2L, 10L)), .Names = c("DoM", "Year", "Month"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

> x
        DoM Year Month
 1: 2011241 2011     8
 2: 2015359 2015    12
 3: 2016352 2016    12
 4: 2015360 2015    12
 5: 2015287 2015    10
 6: 2014038 2014     2
 7: 2017066 2017     3
 8: 2012227 2012     8
 9: 2015041 2015     2
10: 2015295 2015    10
```

I need to extract the date from the DoM column, which contains the day in a Julian like format. Each element of the DoM column is of the form `yyyyddd`, where `ddd` is the day of the year `yyyy` (and hence `1 <= ddd <= 366`).

E.g. The first date would be `2011-08-29` because it corresponds to the 241<sup>st</sup> day of `2011`

I currently am not satisfied with what I have, which is -

```
x[, Date:=as.Date((DoM-1000*Year)-1, origin=paste(Year,1,1,sep='-'))]
```

I suspect the `paste` is inefficient and was looking for any alternatives that might be better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible with basic formatting. See `?strptime`:

```
as.Date(as.character(x$DoM), format="%Y%j")
# or as @Frank suggests, for integer dates in data.table:
as.IDate(as.character(x$DoM), format="%Y%j")
# [1] "2011-08-29" "2015-12-25" "2016-12-17" "2015-12-26" "2015-10-14"
# [6] "2014-02-07" "2017-03-07" "2012-08-14" "2015-02-10" "2015-10-22"
```

Comment: Or for integer dates which may be faster to work with, `as.IDate(same_code)`.